# PHP: How can i keep two POST value into a variable

Tags: php

Can i Keep two POST Value into a variable.
Like:

```
$value=$_post['value1'] [need a space here] $_post['value2'];
```

is there anything which can do this?

Comment: Hello, @iamlancer. Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are some good answers below. You may also notice that the number beside your question is negative. People have down-voted your question. I would guess that is because they feel you didn't take time to research the answer to your question for yourself. Effort is rewarded here. Also, if you find an answer you like, click the checkmark beside it to tell the answerer you value his/her input. Again, welcome.

Comment: yeah i guess so. I should have done more research on it. Thanks for your advice,

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
    $value = $_POST['value1'] . ' ' . $_POST['value2']; 
?>
```

[Concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Answer (score 1):

PHP concatenates strings using the [`.` operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

```
$value = $_POST['value1'] . ' ' . $_POST['value2'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Can i Keep two POST Value into a variable.
```

You can put your two Post value in 1 variable. Yes, it's called an array.

```
 $value = array($_post['value1'],$_post['value2']);
```

If you want it in 1 string you need to concatenate:

```
 $value = $_POST['value1'] . ' ' . $_POST['value2'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either create an array with the two valurs, or concatenate the two values using the string dot operator